# In VBA replace hard coded cell reference with dynamic in a link

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks one "database" and another "source". What I'm trying to achieve is to set up a loop that would iterate thru a known range in "source" wb and create links in "database". Data in the "source" wb = C7:C38.

Any ideas?
Code below is the one i'm using to pull single values for the links - how can I make it loop thru range C7:C38?

```
Option Explicit

'**********Using ip address to link/locate folders in the the directory. 
Public Sub PullData()
Dim repDate As Date
Dim tmpFileStr As String
Dim tmpPathStr As String
Dim rowCtrLng As Long
Dim startRowCtrLng As Long
Dim stoptRowCtrLng As Long
Dim msgStr As String
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim stopDate
Dim fldName As String
Dim fName As String
Dim fDay As String

'On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Initialize row counter
    startRowCtrLng = 2
    'Get starting row for new data
    Do While ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & startRowCtrLng).Value <> ""
        startRowCtrLng = startRowCtrLng + 1
    Loop
rowCtrLng = startRowCtrLng
    'Assign current date to variable


    'Pause automatic calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    'Disable alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
repDate = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("A" &       rowCtrLng).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
currentDate = Date
fldName = Format(Year(Now), "0000")
fName = Format(Month(Now), "00")
fDay = Format(Day(Now), "0")



'Begin looping through date range
Do While repDate < currentDate

        tmpFileStr = ""
        tmpPathStr = ""


        'Determine if report exists
        tmpPathStr = "\\0.0.0.0\dept\Folder\Subfolder\" & fldName & "\"
        If Dir("\\0.0.0.0\dept\Folder\Subfolder\" & fldName & "\" & fName &  "-" & fldName & ".xls") <> "" Then
            tmpFileStr = fName & "-" & fldName & ".xls"

        Else
            tmpFileStr = ""
        End If

If tmpFileStr <> "" Then
            'build Links
            'Production Date
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rowCtrLng).Value = repDate
            'Crush
             ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rowCtrLng).Value = "='" & tmpPathStr & "[" & tmpFileStr & "]C vol'!$C$7"





End If
rowCtrLng = rowCtrLng + 1

repDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("A" & rowCtrLng).Value
Loop

End Sub
```

'

Comment: Maybe `For x = 7 To 38` or declare, set, increment a constant `x = x + 1`. Use the variable to dynamically construct cell reference.